# use JTidy to convert html file to xml file, but still get html form

Tags: xml, xpath

I an trying to use JTidy to convert html file intp xml file.
here is the example code online given by other:

```
public class Html2Xml {
    private String outFileName;
    private String errOutFileName;

public Html2Xml(String outFileName, String errOutFileName) {
    this.outFileName = outFileName;
    this.errOutFileName = errOutFileName;
}

public void convert() {
    BufferedInputStream in;
    FileOutputStream out;

    Tidy tidy = new Tidy();

    // Tell Tidy to convert HTML to XML
    tidy.setXmlOut(true);
    try {
        // Set file for error messages
        tidy.setErrout(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(errOutFileName), true));
        tidy.setForceOutput(true);
        tidy.setInputEncoding("utf-8");
        tidy.setEncloseText(false);
        tidy.setXmlOut(true);
        // u = new URL(url);
        File f = new File("e:/.../gd.htm");

        // input and output
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Convert files
        tidy.parseDOM(in, out);

        // Clean up
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(this.toString() + e.toString());
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Html2Xml t = new Html2Xml("e:/...../right1.xml", "e:/...../error1.xml");
    t.convert();
}
```

}

it works and can get the output in a xml file format. But when I open it, it still starts with 
`<!DOCTYPE HTML> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "" ""> <html>` and because an XML document is only allowed a single DOCTYPE node or none at all.

so when I am trying to use eclipse xpath plugin to get xpath of an anchor element in the file, it always shows org.xml.sax.saxparseexception: already seen doctype (I think it's because multiple same elements in the xml file).

Thanks in advance for any help!